# SQL Where if else

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How do i do translate this linq code into sql?

```
if (storeId > 1)
            {
                query = from p in query
                        where (p.StoreId == storeId) 
                        select p;
            }
```

If storeId > 1 i don't want to do a WHERE comparison in SQL.

UPDATE
Here is what i would like to do in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE (
  (test.city = @city)
  AND 
  (test.price = @price)
  AND
  (
  IF (@storeId > 1)
    test.storeId = @storeId
  ELSE
    do not do anything 
  )
)
```

Comment: I don't understand... if you just want to convert it to SQL, why not just run it and see what SQL is executed? What do you mean?

Comment: @Mark - the OP wants to (I think) include the outer `if` clause in his SQL query. The LINQ query generated by the code above won't include that.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself: The code you provided seems to do a query (including a WHERE-claue) exactly when storeId > 1. Or am I missing something? Can you make your intention clearer?

Comment: I have updated my answer after looking at your update. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from p where p.storeid = @storeid or @storeid > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it looks like you WANT To retrieve a specific storeId record if storeId > 1. I am also assuming that you meant you do NOT WANT a where clause if storeId <=1.
If my assumptions are correct, the SQL you are after is probably as below:

```
Select * from p where (@storeId > 1 and p.storeId = @storeId) or @storeId <= 1
```

After looking at your update to the question, this SQL should work for you:

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE  test.city = @city AND test.price = @price 
 AND ((@storeId > 1 AND test.storeId = @storeId) or @storeId <=1)
```

Please note that if @storeId <=1, it will return all the records that match the City and Price. If this is not what you want and do not want any records returned when @storeId <= 1, then you can remove the last OR condition as below:

```
 SELECT * FROM test WHERE  test.city = @city AND test.price = @price 
 AND (@storeId > 1 AND test.storeId = @storeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var queryresult = from p in query
                  where ((p.StoreId == storeId) && (storeId > 1)) 
                        || (storeId <= 1)
                  select p;
```